# Two sorted array, perform swaps so that each element in the first is smaller than any of the elements in the second

Tags: algorithm

I need to create an algorithm to solve the following problem:

Given two sorted arrays (both have `n` elements) I need to modify them so that each element in the first array is smaller than any element in the second array. The operations I could do is compare two elements and swap two elements.

My first solutions is this:

Let a be the last element of the first array and let b be the first element of the second array. If `a<b` then we stop, otherwise we swap them and continue with arrays n-1 smaller (erase last element in the first, the first in the second).

This is obviously linear.

But what if I wanted to minimize the number of comparisons made in this algorithm? In this one I make a linear number of swaps and comparisons. Could I go smaller with comparisons?

I could do a double binary search I think. Meaning I search for such element a' in the first array that is bigger then some element b' in the second array but smaller then the one next to him. This has complexity `O(lg n^2)`. Can I do better?

Comment: @ArtjomB This is perfectly on topic, there is a programming problem, and the OP described two solutions to solve it. He is asking for a more efficient one (as described), the fact that there is no code is not relevant, any semi-descent programmer can code these algorithms once they are clear.  On the other hand, questions in CodeReview.SE must show a (working) code.

Comment: Does the output have to be sorted and do you want that the two resulting arrays are again of size `n`? Also, complexity `O(lg n^2)` is essentially `O(n)`

Comment: Tables don't have to be sorted and they both have to be of size n

Comment: @ArtjomB. `O(lg n^2) is not equal to O(n)`

Comment: @smttsp Yes, you are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not working with `O(lg n^2)`.

With binary search you will decrease the number of comparison from O(n) to log(n), but the number of swap operation will still be `O(n)`

Yes, your algorithm will be slightly improved but the complexity stays the same. You **have to** do `k` number of swaps where `0<=k<=n`